# IndexError: list assignment index out of range?

Tags: python, list, indexing, variable-assignment

How to fix this error ?!
The code is

```
from datetime import datetime
with open("1.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
lines[1] = datetime.today().strftime('%A %d %B %Y at %I:%M %p')
with open("1.txt", "w") as f:
    f.writelines(lines)
```

The error

````
  File "test.py", in <module>
    lines[1] = datetime.today().strftime('%A %d %B %Y')
IndexError: list assignment index out of range```
````

Answer (score 0):

What is the content of 1.txt? Assuming there is only one line in the file and you want to **update the line**, you have to do so with the first index which is [0] therefore:

```
lines[0] = datetime.today().strftime('%A %d %B %Y at %I:%M %p')
```

If you want to **add a line** you have to use

```
lines.append(datetime.today().strftime('%A %d %B %Y at %I:%M %p'))
```

Comment: Great! If it answered your question you can mark the answer by clicking on the gray checkmark next to the answer.